# javascript buttons + css transition flicker on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button set like this, controlled by javascript and trigger  css transition, I tried to duplicate the problem into some more simplify situation , but the flickering just won't happen, but only happen on this button set, the problem might not be even inside this code, or it might be.

The output is, when mouse over the button, it flickers for 0.5 second on webkit browser, if put `border:2px solid red` on the buttons, the background size will not be 100% anymore, looks buggy
I've tried putting :

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform      : translateZ(0); 
-webkit-transform      : translate3d(0,0,0);    
-webkit-perspective:1000;
```

All helpless.. Did I do anything wrongly?

```
 var btns = {
         'bg_o' : ['images/services/btn1.png','images/services/btn2.png','images/services/btn3.png','images/services/btn4.png'],
         'bg_h' : ['images/services/btn1_hover.png','images/services/btn2_hover.png','images/services/btn3_hover.png','images/services/btn4_hover.png'],
         '$all_btn' : $('.all_btn'),
         '$folders':[$('#folder1'),$('#folder2'),$('#folder3'),$('#folder4')],
         'folders_status':['inactive','inactive','inactive','inactive'],
         'timer':null
         ,jquery_func : function(){
            btns.$all_btn.each(function(){

                $(this).click(function(){
                    if($(this).attr('id')=='service_btn1'){
                        ajax1();
                    }

                    if($(this).attr('id')=='service_btn3'){
                        ajax3();
                    }
                    var imageurl_o = new Array();

                    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                        imageurl_o[i] = {'background':'url('+btns.bg_o[i]+')','background-size':'100% 100%'};       
                        btns.$folders[i].css(imageurl_o[i]);    
                        btns.folders_status[i]='inactive';
                    }

                    for(i=0;i<4;i++){           
                        var myparent = btns.$folders[i].parent();                       
                        if($(this).attr('class') == myparent.attr('class')){
                            var imageurl_h = {'background':'url('+btns.bg_h[i]+')','background-size':'100% 100%'};
                            btns.$folders[i].css(imageurl_h);   
                            btns.folders_status[i]='active';
                        }   
                    }
                });


                $(this).on('mouseenter',function(){
                    console.log('out')
                    var imageurl_o = new Array();

                    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                        imageurl_o[i] = {'background':'url('+btns.bg_o[i]+')','background-size':'100% 100%'};
                    }
                    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                        if(btns.folders_status[i]=='inactive'){
                            btns.$folders[i].css(imageurl_o[i]);
                        }
                    }


                    clearTimeout(btns.timer);
                    var imageurl_h = null;
                    var go = null;
                    for(i=0;i<4;i++){           
                        var myparent = btns.$folders[i].parent();                       
                        if($(this).is(':visible')&&$(this).attr('class') == myparent.attr('class')){
                            $(this).stop(true);
                                imageurl_h = {'background':'url('+btns.bg_h[i]+')','background-size':'100% 100%'};
                                go=imageurl_h;
                                if(imageurl_h!=null && go!=null){
                                    btns.$folders[i].css(go);   
                                    btns.$folders[i].css(go);   
                                    btns.$folders[i].css(go);   

                                }
                        }   
                    }

                    btns.timer = setTimeout(function(){
                        var imageurl_o = new Array();
                        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                            imageurl_o[i] = {'background':'url('+btns.bg_o[i]+')','background-size':'100% 100%'};
                        }
                        for(i=0;i<4;i++){

                            if(btns.folders_status[i]=='inactive')
                            btns.$folders[i].css(imageurl_o[i]);
                        }
                    },1000);


                });


            }); 
         }
     }
     btns.jquery_func();
```